# Form display message when all items have been deleted from list

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to delete items from a list that populates from a drop down list and  want the to display a message saying there are no items in the list once all items have been deleted. 
The lines commented out should make it work however I cant seem to to get i right. 
If anyone could help that would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

```
public partial class DeleteBook : System.Web.UI.Page
{
public Catalogue catalogueInstance = new Catalogue();

//Filepath for json file
const string FILENAME = 
@"C:\Users\tstra\Desktop\19456932_CSE2ICX_Assessment_3\Bin\Books.json";


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string jsonText = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);
    // reading data contained in the json filepath
    //convert objects in json file to lists
    catalogueInstance = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Catalogue>(jsonText);

    if (IsPostBack) return;

    ddlDelete.DataSource = catalogueInstance.books;
    ddlDelete.DataTextField = "title";
    ddlDelete.DataValueField = "id";

    ddlDelete.Items.Insert(0, "There are no items in the Catalogue to 
Display");

    //binding the data to Drop Down List
    ddlDelete.DataBind();
}

protected void ddlDelete_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string jsonText = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);
    // reading data contained in the json filepath
    //convert objects in json file to lists
    catalogueInstance = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Catalogue>(jsonText);

    Book b = catalogueInstance.books[ddlDelete.SelectedIndex - 1];
    txtID.Text = b.id.ToString();
    txtTitle.Text = b.title;
    txtAuthor.Text = b.author;
    txtYear.Text = b.year.ToString();
    txtPublisher.Text = b.publisher;
    txtISBN.Text = b.isbn;
}

protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    // Get the catalogue instance again (gone stale)
    Catalogue catalogueInstance = new Catalogue();
    // get the book id.
    ddlDelete.DataSource = catalogueInstance.books;
    // Get the book.

    Book b = catalogueInstance.books[ddlDelete.SelectedIndex - 1];
    txtID.Text = b.id.ToString();
    txtTitle.Text = b.title;
    txtAuthor.Text = b.author;
    txtYear.Text = b.year.ToString();
    txtPublisher.Text = b.publisher;
    txtISBN.Text = b.isbn;

    // Delete the book from catalogue instance
    catalogueInstance.books.RemoveAt(ddlDelete.SelectedIndex - 1);

    ddlDelete.SelectedIndex = 0;

    // serialise and write catalogue instance to file.
    catalogueInstance.books.RemoveAt(ddlDelete.SelectedIndex - 1);

    ddlDelete.SelectedIndex = 0;

    // rebind the ddl.
    ddlDelete.DataBind();

    int id = Int32.Parse(txtID.Text);
    Book book = catalogueInstance.books.SingleOrDefault(b => b.id == id);
    //catalogueInstance.books.Remove(book);

    catalogueInstance.books.RemoveAt(ddlDelete.SelectedIndex - 1);

    ddlDelete.SelectedIndex = 0;


    //ddlDelete_SelectedIndexChanged(ddlDelete, new EventArgs());

    if (book != null)
    {

        book.title = txtTitle.Text;
        book.year = Int32.Parse(txtYear.Text);
        book.author = txtAuthor.Text;
        book.publisher = txtPublisher.Text;
        book.isbn = txtISBN.Text;

        string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(catalogueInstance);
        File.WriteAllText(FILENAME, jsonText);
    }
    txtSummary.Text = "Book ID of " + id + " has Been deleted from the 
Catalogue" + Environment.NewLine;

    if (!catalogueInstance.books.Any())
    {
        txtSummary.Text = "There are no items in the Catalogue";
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that exception is never thrown cause your file always exists. Removing all items from the file doesn't mean that the file will be removed as well. You need to change your code a bit. You can either check catalogueInstance.books that it doesn't have any books or check File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);. I would check the 1 one:

```
if(!catalogueInstance.books.Any()){
    txtSummary.Text = "There are no items in the Catalogue";
}
```

So you can remove your try-catch block.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? It doesn't show message or what? Could you send updated code?